# Rails view call another model and pass a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a scaffold `Currency` and a model `Neural Network` connected by `:has_one` and `:belongs_to` respectively. I want to create a form in `Currency`'s `show` view which takes as parameter an integer from 1 to 30 from the user. When the user submits the form, I want it to call a method from the `Neural Network` model (for the instance which corresponds to the current currency) and pass the integer as a parameter.

How can I code this in the view?

Comment: When the user submits the form, the `Currency` controller will have access to all permitted parameters from the form within whatever action you configure.  So if the form has action `foo`, then the `foo` method in the controller is invoked.  From there, you can use form parameters as you like, including invoking methods in other models with them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) to allow one model to call other model's methods

```
class Greeter < ActiveRecord::Base
 def hello
  'hello'
 end

 def goodbye
   'goodbye'
 end
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :greeter
  delegate :hello, to: :greeter
end

Foo.new.hello   # => "hello"
Foo.new.goodbye # => NoMethodError: undefined method `goodbye' for    #<Foo:0x1af30c>
```

What exactly do you mean by 'how do I code the view'?

If you would like to save two models with data from the single form, you should use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)